# How to extract from a list based on a partial alphanumeric string?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following list. I've tried various ways to extract only those pairs in the list where **both** elements have the string N36. Given the below, the output would be just {N36012,N36321} and {N36040,N36098}. Suggestions are most welcomed!

```
lst = {{N36061, N35100}, {N36012, N36321}, {N36040, N36098}, {N8100, 
    N36010}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

lst = {{N36061, N35100}, {N36012, N36321}, {N36040, N36098}, {N8100, N36010}};

Select[lst, 
 And @@ {StringContainsQ[ToString@#[[1]], "N36"], 
    StringContainsQ[ToString@#[[2]], "N36"]} &]

(* {{N36012, N36321}, {N36040, N36098}} *)
```

Or

```
Select[lst, AllTrue[#, StringContainsQ[ToString@#, "N36"] &] &]

(* {{N36012, N36321}, {N36040, N36098}} *)
```

Comment: Many thanks, Bob ... I wasn't aware of the StringContainsQ ... thank u ...prg

Comment: With operator forms: `Select[lst, AllTrue[StringStartsQ["N36"]]]`

Answer (score 5):

There is a built in `StringStartsQ`. You can define a function to determine whether items in a list share a prefix:

```
PrefixMatch[prefix_String, list_List] := 
  AllTrue[ToString /@ list, StringStartsQ[prefix]]
```

With that, you can use `Select`:

```
Select[lst, PrefixMatch["N36", #] &]
```

Comment: PrefixMatch!! very nice ... thank u!!

Answer (score 3):

> have the string N36.

It you meant starts with "N36" and not has this string anywhere, another option is

```
lst = {{"N36061", "N35100"}, {"N36012", "N36321"}, {"N36040", "N36098"}, {"N8100", "N36010"}}
pat = "N36" ~~ __;
StringMatchQ[First[#], pat] && StringMatchQ[Last[#], pat] & /@ lst;
Pick[lst, %]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nasser: That is a very nice option too; I was not familiar with your second line of code ... thank u very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
lst = {{"N36061", "N35100"}, {"N36012", "N36321"}, {"N36040", 
   "N36098"}, {"N8100", "N36010"}}

Pick[lst, And @@@ Map[StringContainsQ["N36"], lst, {2}]]

Pick[lst, AllTrue[#, StringContainsQ["N36"]] & /@ lst]

DeleteCases[lst, {OrderlessPatternSequence[_?(StringFreeQ[
      "N36"]), _]}]
```

---

*Result*

> {{"N36012", "N36321"}, {"N36040", "N36098"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = {{"N36061", "N35100"}, {"N36012", "N36321"}, {"N36040", "N36098"}, {"N8100", "N36010"}}

sel[x_] /; And @@ Map[StringStartsQ["N36"], x] := x
sel[_] := Nothing

sel /@ lst
```

{{"N36012", "N36321"}, {"N36040", "N36098"}}

Answer (score 1):

```
checkPre = ToString /* StringMatchQ[RegularExpression["^N36.*"]];

{{N36061, N35100}, {N36012, N36321}, {N36040, N36098}, {N8100, N36010}} //
Cases[{_?checkPre, _?checkPre}]
```